# Pointer to a pointer's attribute

Tags: c++, pointers

Is there any way to simulate this situation in C++?

I have two objects `A` and `B`, each one has one attribute, for example, `int i`;
Also I have one pointer `po` pointing to an object and one pointer `pi` pointing to an integer. I want to have the integer pointer pointing to the attribute in the current object pointed by the pointer.
Something like:

```
po = A;
pi = po->i;
// pi points to A.i
po = B;
// now pi points to B.i
```

I'm almost sure this can't be achieved using pointers, but I want to know if there's any work around to do it.

Comment: This COULD be done with some structure that behaves like pointer to int but holds a reference to some other pointer, as well as one pointer-to-member. But really, why complicating things? Whatever you are trying to accomplish there surely is a more elegant way.

Comment: I'm guessing, according to your description B is derived from A (you are assigning pointers.) If so, A::i is the same as B::i. You need to clarify, what you are actually doing, before anybody would be able to help you.

Comment: In all seriousness though, I would not employ this magic in real code - why don't you simply provide an accessor method for `i`?

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is called 'pointers to members'. Suppose that A and B are of type T, then you can write:

```
struct T { int i; };
T A, B, C; // some objects of this type

int T::*pi = &T::i; // pi is a pointer to an int member of T

T* po;
po = &A;
cout << po->*pi << '\n'; // prints A.i
po = &B;
cout << po->*pi << '\n'; // prints B.i

cout << C.*pi << '\n'; // prints C.i
```

Comment: Yeah, this is probably what OP really wants.  But it's not what was asked for, which is why I requested further clarification. +1

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can't do that straight forward.
`pi` would have to be notified/changed if `po` changes. With `pi` being an object of a new ty pe `AutoReference` you could achieve it, but nobody will understand the code.
What I mean with "not straight forward" is: The following works but don't do it.

```
class AutoReference
{
public:
  AutoReference( ClassA ** ppObj )
  : mppObj( ppObj )
  {
  }

  ClassA * operator->()
  {
    return *mppObj;
  }

private:
  ClassA ** mppObj;
};


po = A;
AutoReference pi( &po );
// pi "points" to A.i
po = B;
// now pi "points" to B.i
```

Comment: Actually I don't like the name `AutoReference` :-(

Comment: +1 you should also implement operator & and *& so as to provide a full smart pointer. but I like your idea better than mine, it is simpler, less heavy than mine.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct O
{
    int i;
};

struct P
{
    void operator=(O & rhs)
    {
        po = &rhs;
        pi = &rhs.i;
    }

    O * po;
    int * pi;
};

int main()
{
    P po;
    int *& pi = po.pi;

    O A,B;
    A.i = 7;
    B.i = 19;

    po = A;
    cout << *pi << endl;
    po = B;   
    cout << *pi << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you could just do a pointer to the pointer, if that suits your situation better.

```
T a, b;
a.i = 6;
b.i = 9;

T* po = &a;
T** pi = &po;
std::cout << (*pi)->i;  // Prints 6

po = &b;
std::cout << (*pi)->i;  // Prints 9
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have written it:

pi continues to point to A.i when po points to B.

What's wrong with using

```
po = &A;
// do stuff using po and po->i (A and A.i)

po = &B;
// do stuff using po and po->i (B and B.i)
```

Comment: Well, a valid question, but it doesn't attempt to answer OP's *actual question*

Answer (score 0):

In short, this cannot be done the way you have specified.  Nor would you *really* want it to.

Just imagine the chaos that would rain down on your application if changing one variable also changed other completely distinct variables.  It would be like dogs & cats living together.  Mass hysteria.

But there's also little point to doing exactly what you've asked for, and this makes me think that what you're *really* after is something else entirely.  For example, in your above example, it would be much simpler to just do this:

```
po = A;
int ai = po->i;
po = B;
int ab = po->i;
```

So, what are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: Not exactly.  You said (paraphrasing) "why not do this?"  I said "You can't do that.  What do you really want to do? In your contrived example, why not do this?"

Answer (score 0):

This would work, but I find this **ugly**.

```
class MyObject
{
public:
 int m_i;

};

class AutomaticPointerToMember
{
    public:
 AutomaticPointerToMember(MyObject& obj,int MyObject::*):
 m_Object(obj),
 m_pInt(NULL)
 {}

    operator int* ()
 {
  return &(m_Object.*m_pInt);
 }

 int operator* ()
 {
  return (m_Object.*m_pInt);
 }

private:
 MyObject& m_Object;
 int MyObject::* m_pInt;
};

void test()
{
 MyObject a;
 MyObject b;

 MyObject * pObj =  &a;
 AutomaticPointerToMember pi(*pObj, &MyObject::m_i);

 int * pIa = pi; // pIa  points to a.i
    int ia = *pi; // value a.i

 pObj = &b; // pObj now points to b

 int * pIb = pi; // pIb  points to b.i

    int ib = *pi; // value b.i
}
```

and one would have to define also operator &, *& and so on, so as to define a politically correct smart pointer...

Answer (score -4):

```
struct S {
   int i;
};


S a, b;
A * ap = & a;
int * ip = &(ap->i);
```

ip now points at a's i member (note these are not referred to as attributes in C++ land)

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for. He wants a way to automatically change the value of `pi` when `po` is changed.

Comment: He said "I want to have the integer pointer pointing to the attribute in the current object pointed by the pointer" which is what the code I posted does.

Comment: Read the comments in his code example - that's where the requirement @Space_C0wb0y mentions is expressed.